# Can i use the plugin Vue DEVTOLLS to change the vuex state of a production application?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-devtools

I'm implementing a login functionality in a vue.js system.
I'm storing the state of the logged in user in userIsAuthenticated and the question arose:
Can I use the Vue DEVTOLLS plugin to change the vuex state of a production application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can

1. Using [Force Vue](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vue-force-dev/oohfffedbkbjnbpbbedapppafmlnccmb)
2. Manually enable the devtools

   To do that you only need to do this in the `main.js`

   `Vue.config.devtools = true`

   This option’s default value is `true` in development builds and `false` in production builds. You can set it to true to enable inspection for production builds.

   Then you can open the devtools and go to the Vuex section and change what you need.

   More info: [devtools](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#devtools)